# Is there any study about the impact on the continuous use of predictive keyboard by neurologically and psychologically health individuals?

Tags: social-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, emotion, experimental-psychology, computational-modeling

As there is [evidence of massive-scale emotional contagion through social networks](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/24/8788.full), I'd like to know if any study has been made regarding predictive keyboards.

Given the popularity of predictive keyboards in the mobile space, I would say that there is a good chance that similar effect can be measured.

Such keyboards come with pre-trained models that usually adapt to the user's behavior, even faster if it has the grants and features to analyze previous user written content. I believe that it can lead to self feeding spirals on the psychological side and, depending on the age group, neurological effects but I would like to know what has been researched already.

The question on the title is meant to be a focused starting point as, depending on the answer I would have the vocabulary to actually make many others (some probably very obvious given the above mentioned).